# BIOS patch to IMM on IBM x3650

Tags: patch, bios

The broader problem is that we're PXE booting an IBM x3650. We can see the console output by ssh-ing to the IMM. However, when it finishes installing it reboots and freezes. We can't connect to the IMM by HTTPS using either JAVA or ActiveX.

So, I'd like to install the BIOS extension to the IMM. I've found five candidates to far, the nearest being ibm_def_bios_gfe123a_anyos_intel32.exe where patchadd reports:

`Wrote new patch <GF[23->23] (BIOS)> to --host`

But subsequently, patchlist doesn't show it. Which patchfile should I be using?

Comment: Dave you'll better served at serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend to contact IBM technical support while server is still on stock firmware.

You'll require server part number and serial number for that. Different revisions of x3650 require different firmware.
If techsupport is not an option, I'd try to search IMM update by server part number. There should be no fuzziness, all firmware is bound to specific model or several models. 
If there are several patches for this exact part number you should:

1. Read installation manual, may be it requires sequential upgrade (though it mostly happened on DS storage systems).
2. Choose latest firmware available.

Most common problem in your case is browser incompatibility. If it's just x3650 (not M2, M3, M4) and you haven't updated IMM firmware, then try to use [old version](https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/) of firefox (around 20. - 30. version). We never had problem with it.

---[ edit n+1 ]---
Do I get it right, that you are able to connect IMM?
[image: x3650 IMM]

Se also not on Java + Firefox remote issue [here](https://datacentersupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/servers/system-x/system-x3650-m5/8871/solutions/ht503750). (assuming you have newer x3650 model, M4+)

I'd recommend to use IBM Java 1.6/1.8 to interact with IBM System x servers. Quick glance shows that it's not that easy to find this versions.

Comment: Enabling SSL gets us into the console. Attaching to the KVM doesn't work. I've upgraded to the latest firmware 1.50. The README files specify that the x3650 is supported.